# Structuring an application using wcf

Tags: .net, wcf

i am new to wcf and i am creating a test application which i structured like this:
[image]

I have few question:
1) is it ok this separation, entities+data access+client+server?
2) how do i manage connection string? i added it to the app.config on the service and i seem to get an exception :Unable to load the specified metadata resource.
3)does it make any point to make a separate dll for transfer objects over the generated once, which means something like  data access+transfer objects+client+server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend looking into the "[Web Service Software Factory 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699490.aspx)" which is a part of the Guidance Automation Extensions (GAX) that are available in Visual Studio.

The solution structure it provides is based on the recommendations of Microsoft's Patterns and Practices team.  You may find that the overall solution can be a bit too much depending on the complexity of the project and the size of the organization you work for.  However, it provides a good starting point for you solution and can be tailored to suit your needs.

**Update:**
Sorry, I realize now that I only answered your first question.  In concern to your other questions, as a practice I always keep the connection strings in the config file of the project that will be compiled to host your application.  This will most likely be a Web Application Project that can be deployed to IIS, but it could just as likely be a Windows Service or Console / Forms Application.  By keeping the connection strings in the config file, you implement loose coupling of the compiled code and the database locations.  I find this to be useful and I have enjoyed, on numerous occasions, the benefit of only needing to change the endpoint in a connection string after database migrations / upgrades.

Comment: @Gigi, I decided it might be worthwhile for me to provide the Solution template that is generated so that you don't need to install the extensions.  I've uploaded a ZIP file containing the solution to my blog site: http://www.bloggedbychris.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Services2.zip.  Some of the items (such as the 'Generated Code' folders) may seem odd when viewing the solution.  That is because these are utilized when you use the Guidance package.

Comment: I took a look at the project you sent to me and it seems to have nothing in common with using self tracking entities, there will be POCO classes and the calls to stored procedures(data access), business entities(businesss entities) and the transfer objects ( data contracts). It is a very clean separation indeed but i think there will be kinda 3 type of entities with almost the same properties.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I guess I was more focused on the separation of concerns in the realm of your "Service" project.  I might split that into a service project, a contracts project, and so forth, depending on the scalability needs of your organization.  I think the way you have the data layers split up is sufficient though.  I might add an additional project for repositories, but it's definitely good practice, at the least, to separate the DAL from your entities as it enables you to swap out the database implementation and not have to regenerate the entity model.

Comment: it's clear for me now that this separation of concerns is directly proportional to the complexity of the project, anyway, i don't see what i am doing wrong with that connection string. I keep it in the service's app.config and i get that exception "Unable to load the specified metadata resource", it seems not to find the .edmx file. that's strange. Any tip?

Comment: @gigi Still not certain why yours is not working without testing your solution. However, I may still be able to help you :) I've been meaning to setup a solution structure that I can templify for my team, and you provided me the perfect opportunity to do so. Hopefully the following solution will help you: bloggedbychris.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/…. This compiles fine and I believe it demonstrates the approach you are taking. You'll need to configure and deploy the Database project in order to debug though.